# how to open new instance of acrobat

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using windows 10 task view and need to open different instances of excel word and acrobat.
I can't seem to get acrobat working. I get error: 0x800401F3 - Invalid class string on the `AcroApp := ComObjCreate("AcroExch.App")` line.
Any suggestions?

```
^+n::
oWord := ComObjCreate("Word.Application")
oWord.Documents.Add
oWord.Visible := 1
oWord.Activate
xlApp := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible := true
xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
xlApp := ""
run notepad
run chrome
AcroApp := ComObjCreate("AcroExch.App"); Error when running
AcroApp.Visible := true
AcroApp.Open
return
```

Answer (score 1):

While the COM approach seems cool, it seems really unnecessary.
I don't have Acrobat, but a quick Google search tells me they have a command line option to open a new instance, as I suspected (documented [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acrobat_SDK_developer_faq.pdf#page=24)).

So, a quick little run command should do the trick:

```
Run, % """C:\Path\To\Acrobat.exe"" /n"
```

Also, maybe [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-sdk/unable-to-createobject-quot-acroexch-app-quot/m-p/10252186) is why your COM approach didn't work?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Where can I read more on the "/n" options at the end of a run function. That helps significantly

Comment: Pretty much any program will have commandline arguments, usually you can find what they support via a Google search.